# on refresh how to stay on same route in angular6?

Tags: angular6

in my code two components are present.
1)app component
2)login component
after login it is going to another page.but on refresh it comes to login page.please solve this issue.i am using angular6.please provide code how to solve this problem.

```
app.module.ts
--------------------------------
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PloginComponent } from './plogin/plogin.component';
import { AfterploginComponent } from './afterplogin/afterplogin.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PloginComponent,
    AfterploginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
   RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
      path : 'after-login',
      component : AfterploginComponent
      },
      {
        path : 'before-login',
        component : PloginComponent
      }

    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

app.component.ts
-------------------------------------------------
import { Component ,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'login';

  constructor(private router :Router){

  }
  ngOnInit(){
    this.router.navigateByUrl('before-login');
  }

  }
```

i am beginer to angular6.on refresh how to stay on same page i don't know.
plese tell me the different approaches to solve the problem easily.

Comment: After successfully login... Are you changing route?

Comment: yes,i am changing route to /after-login

Comment: Do you store any session or values in localstorage afrer successful login? how do you check whether is login or not? @MulsaPrathap

Comment: i am passing login credentials to nodejs by using httpclient request and receiving by using bodyparser and sending sucess or not  response. but on refresh it is moving to login page. i am new to angular tell me how to solve it.

Comment: please suggest as quickly as possible